# How can i use optional class by using string

Tags: java, java-8

I am learning java 8. How can i use in optional class as string? eclipse is saying to remove arguments as optional is not generic.

```
String s = "Hi I am karthik";
    
Optional<String> checkNull = Optional.ofNullable(s);
```

below error is showing in eclipse

> The type Optional is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: java.util.Optional<T> is, in fact, generic. Are you importing the correct class? Which JDK are you using?

Comment: @Taschi

java version "1.8.0_191"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: And your import statement?

Comment: I didnt import anything because eclipse didnt allow me to import.

Comment: Rename your class to something other than "Optional". That is confusing the compiler. Or, as Viktor Reinok said, use fully-qualified types (but that is ugly and you should avoid it).

Comment: That message is impossible to get if you actually did import `java.util.Optional`. You must have been imported some other `Optional`.

Answer (score 2):

You stated in the comments that your class is called `Optional`. That is confusing the compiler because that type name is now ambiguous, so within this compilation unit (i. e. this Java file) every time you refer to `Optional`, the compiler will think you are referring to your own class, rather than `java.util.Optional`.

Solution: Rename your class, and the corresponding Java file, to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
java.util.Optional<String> checkNull = java.util.Optional.ofNullable("Hi I am karthik");
```

Make sure your eclipse has java 8 in classpath. So, check your IDE configuration.

Comment: This will fix OP's problem but generally, if you need to use fully-qualified type names, you *really* should reconsider your type names and resolve the ambiguity, rather than just use fully-qualified type names as a workaround.